# Rsync Include and Exclude with Dates

Tags: rsync, filter

I have a bunch of log files that I sync with another server using rsync.  The log files are all named in the format YYYY-MM-DD XXX.txt.  I only want to sync the current month and last month of logs but my filters seem to be conflicting.  Here's what I have in my include/exclude file:

```
- 2009*
- 2010*
- 2011*
- 2012*
- 2013*
+ 2013-03*
+ 2013-04*
```

The includes/excludes above causes nothing to be synced (I'm assuming because the `-2013*` appears before the specific months.  However, if I remove `-2013*` from the file above and just leave the 2013-03 and 2013-04, it wants to sync any file beginning with 2013.

I know I'm missing something in the order or format of my filters.  Was wondering if anyone had a suggestion.  Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`- 2013*` excludes everything from 2013, this isn't getting reversed if you do a more specific include later.

Try

```
+ 2013-03*
+ 2013-04*
- 2013*
```

and refer to the "Filtering rules" section of the [man page](http://www.samba.org/ftp/rsync/rsync.html) for more info.

Comment: PERFECT - that did the trick.  I feel like I just had a DUH moment.  Thank you for your help!  PS - You can ignore my question to you in a previous thread.  Looks like this was the issue!

Answer (score 2):

The manual is explicit about this:

> As the list of files/directories to transfer is built, rsync checks each name to be transferred against  the  list
>   of  include/exclude  patterns  in  turn, and **the first matching pattern is acted on**:  if it is an exclude pattern,
>   then that file is skipped; if it is an include pattern then that filename is not skipped; *if no  matching  pattern
>   is found, then the filename is not skipped*.